# Tracking User Activity in Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, mobile, monitoring

We're trying to track mobile user activity for session (iOS and Android).
Each session would begin tracking once the user opens the app.

1. We're tracking

   a) Time inside each screen

   b) Map of User Touches on each screen

   c) How long from the first time user signs up does he click on a certain    button (Main feature of the app)

   d) Duration between each new session

   e) Total time spent in each session

   f) How many force closes or crashes

What language is recommended for this? Are there Libraries that have these functions built in iOS or are publicly available?

Answer (score -2):

You can accomplish this using the following tools:
1. Adobe Analytics
2. Crittercism (For Crash Reporting)

Both have solutions for Android.